# Model's Ignored property does not seem to get set using init(value: Any)

Tags: swift, realm

I am facing an issue where I am unable to set an ignored property through `init(value: Any)`. The way I understood ignored properties is that they are present in an instance of an Object and once the object is persisted to the `Realm`, they will be ignored, however it seems like they are ignored already during initialization.

Example:

**Model**:

```
class Image: Object {

    dynamic var main = false
    dynamic var image: UIImage?

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["image"]
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let img = Image(value: [PROPERTY.MAIN: imageSlot.imageInfo.main, PROPERTY.IMAGE: imageSlot.imageInfo.image])
img.image // NIL HERE

let img = Image(value: [PROPERTY.MAIN: imageSlot.imageInfo.main])
img.image = imageSlot.imageInfo.image
img.image // CORRECTLY SET
```

It is just a bit annoying that I cannot set it already in the init(value: Any) and therefore I was wondering whether this is an intended behavior or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes you can set it in the initializer.  Show us the initializer you wrote so we can see what went wrong. This should be straightforward to fix. -- kye just provided a very good solution for you.

Comment: @Mozahler the answer you are referring to was factually wrong and has been deleted by its writer. OP uses the default initialiser used by `Realm`, it is not a custom initialiser written by OP.

Comment: I understood that the OP was not using a custom initializer. It is my opinion that this is what is required. That is why I asked he provide the code. I appreciate your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior currently. The `Object.init(value:)` initializer only considers keys for persisted properties at the moment.

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3495

The solution is you can define custom initializer like `init(main: Bool, image: UIImage?)`.

```
class Image: Object {
    dynamic var main = false
    dynamic var image: UIImage?

    convenience init(main: Bool, image: UIImage?) {
        self.init()
        self.main = main
        self.image = image
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["image"]
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like the following:

```
let img = Image(main: imageSlot.imageInfo.main, image: imageSlot.imageInfo.image)
```